# Jagged voxel terrain using simplex noise 2D

Tags: c++, voxel

My goal is to implement a voxel terrain system for Unreal Engine, and things went well until I produced a bunch of chunks with jagged voxel terrains.
I used simplex noise 2d to calculate the height value. However, I found that each chunk had a specific hightmap, which resulted incoherent and jagged voxel terrain.
So, how can we create smooth terrains which consist of chunks that use the same heightmap using simplex noise 2d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have the texture seamless, you need to set up the underlying noise funtion in such a way that interpolation at the edges of the tiles will result in the same values; it is impossible to obtain the desired result with noise functions which are completely independent from each other in each tile. The approach is discussed in detail [here](https://www.gamedev.net/topic/639342-infinite-terrain-generation-in-chunks-need-hints-on-handling-chunk-edges/).

Comment: Are there any sample codes or pseudo codes available? There're too many pieces of information in that thread. Can you point out which thread talks about the answer in the link?

Comment: I solved this problem by writing this: USimplexNoise2D(VoxelLoc.x, VoxelLoc.y); instead of USimplexNosie2D(ChunkLoc.x, ChunkLoc.y);